# Identifying Objects in Firebase PreBuilt UI in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication

FirebaseUI has a nice pre-buit UI for Swift. I'm trying to position an image view above the login buttons on the bottom. In the example below, the imageView is the "Hackathon" logo. Any logo should be able to show in this, if it's called "logo", since this shows the image as aspectFit.

According to the Firebase docs page:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui

You can customize the signin screen with this function:

```
func authPickerViewController(forAuthUI authUI: FUIAuth) -> FUIAuthPickerViewController {
  return FUICustomAuthPickerViewController(nibName: "FUICustomAuthPickerViewController",
                                           bundle: Bundle.main,
                                           authUI: authUI)
}
```

Using this code & poking around with subviews in the debuggers, I've been able to identify and color code views in the image below. Unfortunately, I don't think that the "true" size of these subview frames is set until the view controller presents, so trying to access the frame size inside these functions won't give me dimensions that I can use for creating a new imageView to hold a log. Plus accessing the views with hard-coded index values like I've done below, seems like a pretty bad idea, esp. given that Google has already changed the Pre-Built UI once, adding a scroll view & breaking the code of anyone who set the pre-built UI's background color.

```
func authPickerViewController(forAuthUI authUI: FUIAuth) -> FUIAuthPickerViewController {
    // Create an instance of the FirebaseAuth login view controller
    let loginViewController = FUIAuthPickerViewController(authUI: authUI)

    // Set background color to white
    loginViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    loginViewController.view.subviews[0].backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    loginViewController.view.subviews[0].subviews[0].backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    loginViewController.view.subviews[0].subviews[0].tag = 999
    return loginViewController
}
```

[image]

I did get this to work by adding a tag (999), then in the completion handler when presenting the loginViewController I hunt down tag 999 and call a function to add an imageView with a logo:

```
present(loginViewController, animated: true) {
    if let foundView = loginViewController.view.viewWithTag(999) {
        let height = foundView.frame.height
        print("FOUND HEIGHT: \(height)")
        self.addLogo(loginViewController: loginViewController, height: height)
    }
}

func addLogo(loginViewController: UINavigationController, height: CGFloat) {
    let logoFrame = CGRect(x: 0 + logoInsets, y: self.view.safeAreaInsets.top + logoInsets, width: loginViewController.view.frame.width - (logoInsets * 2), height: self.view.frame.height - height - (logoInsets * 2))

    // Create the UIImageView using the frame created above & add the "logo" image
    let logoImageView = UIImageView(frame: logoFrame)
    logoImageView.image = UIImage(named: "logo")
    logoImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit // Set imageView to Aspect Fit
    // loginViewController.view.addSubview(logoImageView) // Add ImageView to the login controller's main view
    loginViewController.view.addSubview(logoImageView)
}
```

But again, this doesn't seem safe. Is there a "safe" way to deconstruct this UI to identify the size of this button box at the bottom of the view controller (this size will vary if there are multiple login methods supported, such as Facebook, Apple, E-mail)? If I can do that in a way that avoids the hard-coding approach, above, then I think I can reliably use the dimensions of this button box to determine how much space is left in the rest of the view controller when adding an appropriately sized ImageView. Thanks!
John

Answer (score 0):

This should address the issue - allowing a logo to be reliably placed above the prebuilt UI login buttons buttons + avoiding hard-coding the index values or subview locations. It should also allow for properly setting background color (also complicated when Firebase added the scroll view + login button subview).

To use: Create a subclass of FUIAuthDelegate to hold a custom view controller for the prebuilt Firebase UI.

The code will show the logo at full screen behind the buttons if there isn't a scroll view or if the class's private constant fullScreenLogo is set to false.

If both of these conditions aren't meant, the logo will show inset taking into account the class's private logoInsets constant and the safeAreaInsets. The scrollView views are set to clear so that a background image can be set, as well via the private let backgroundColor.

Call it in any signIn function you might have, after setting authUI.providers. Call would be something like this:

```
let loginViewController = CustomLoginScreen(authUI: authUI!)
let loginNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginViewController)
loginNavigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(loginNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And here's one version of the subclass:

```
class CustomLoginScreen: FUIAuthPickerViewController {
    private var fullScreenLogo = false // false if you want logo just above login buttons
    private var viewContainsButton = false
    private var buttonViewHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
    private let logoInsets: CGFloat = 16
    private let backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    private var scrollView: UIScrollView?
    private var viewContainingButton: UIView?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // set color of scrollView and Button view inside scrollView to clear in viewWillAppear to avoid a "color flash" when the pre-built login UI first appears
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        guard let foundScrollView = returnScrollView() else {
            print(" Couldn't get a scrollView.")
            return
        }
        scrollView = foundScrollView
        scrollView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        guard let foundViewContainingButton = returnButtonView() else {
            print(" No views in the scrollView contain buttons.")
            return
        }
        viewContainingButton = foundViewContainingButton
        viewContainingButton!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // Create the UIImageView at full screen, considering logoInsets + safeAreaInsets
        let x = logoInsets
        let y = view.safeAreaInsets.top + logoInsets
        let width = view.frame.width - (logoInsets * 2)
        let height = view.frame.height - (view.safeAreaInsets.top + view.safeAreaInsets.bottom + (logoInsets * 2))
        var frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
        let logoImageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
        logoImageView.image = UIImage(named: "logo")
        logoImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit // Set imageView to Aspect Fit
        logoImageView.alpha = 0.0

        // Only proceed with customizing the pre-built UI if you found a scrollView or you don't want a full-screen logo.
        guard scrollView != nil && !fullScreenLogo else {
            print("No scrollView found.")
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {logoImageView.alpha = 1.0})
            self.view.addSubview(logoImageView)
            self.view.sendSubviewToBack(logoImageView) // otherwise logo is on top of buttons
            return
        }

        // update the logoImageView's frame height to subtract the height of the subview containing buttons. This way the buttons won't be on top of the logoImageView
        frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height - (viewContainingButton?.frame.height ?? 0.0))
        logoImageView.frame = frame
        self.view.addSubview(logoImageView)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {logoImageView.alpha = 1.0})
    }

    private func returnScrollView() -> UIScrollView? {
        var scrollViewToReturn: UIScrollView?
        if self.view.subviews.count > 0 {
            for subview in self.view.subviews {
                if subview is UIScrollView {
                    scrollViewToReturn = subview as? UIScrollView
                }
            }
        }
        return scrollViewToReturn
    }

    private func returnButtonView() -> UIView? {
        var viewContainingButton: UIView?
        for view in scrollView!.subviews {
            viewHasButton(view)
            if viewContainsButton {
                viewContainingButton = view
                break
            }
        }
        return viewContainingButton
    }

    private func viewHasButton(_ view: UIView) {
        if view is UIButton {
            viewContainsButton = true
        } else if view.subviews.count > 0 {
            view.subviews.forEach({viewHasButton($0)})
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps any who have been frustrated trying to configure the Firebase pre-built UI in Swift.